# Cannot render .tmx map using OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer (Android)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, rendering, tmx

I am having a hard time getting a map to display correctly on my android app using LibGdx. First up here is my code:

```
public class PlayState extends State {
  private LittleMan littleMan;
  private TiledMap map;
  OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

  OrthographicCamera camera;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    littleMan = new LittleMan(50,100);
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, w,h);
    camera.update();
    TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = loader.load("ste_barbe_map.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {
}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    // if viewport modified
    // sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
    /*
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(littleMan.getTexture(),littleMan.getPosition().x,littleMan.getPosition().y);
    sb.end();
    */
}

@Override
// free some ressources
public void dispose() {
}
}
```

So when i try to run the app and call the render method i just get a red background with nothing on it. 
Here are some things i tried:

1. using a smaller map with just a line of tiles, this displays correctly (even though i'm not sure its at the right position):

[image: small map]

2. playing around with scaling: i can display the map but its either very small or i can only see the edges

with this line changed to : `tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,0.5f);`I get:

[image: 0.5f scaling]

And with this line :  `tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,1/8f);`

I get this very zoomed out image of the map:

[image]

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong? Maybe my tmx file is bad, maybe it's something with the camera, or something else i really don't know. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: please tell me one tile dimension in pixel ? and how many tile you want to display at a time on screen in horizontal and in vertical ?

Comment: Don't really know yet, for now i just want to be able to display everything and see how the map looks. After that i can tweak certain stuff.

Comment: when you create .tmx file, there you decide one tile dimension and whole map size(number of tile in width and height) ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/89c6703d0d2370ceeb3d5c3f1cdabf8b
These are the settings in the editor

Comment: I might be on to something, here is how the map looks (some one else made it for me). Could it be im rendering the empty parts? https://gyazo.com/29ef2f197921bbd15bc662fbfae88ca6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Camera ViewPort according to your map like this.

```
TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();
map = loader.load("ste_barbe_map.tmx");
tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
TiledMapTileLayer layer=(TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);

float w=layer.getTileWidth()*layer.getWidth();   // 100*34
float h=layer.getTileHeight()*layer.getHeight();  // 100*34

camera=new OrthographicCamera(w,h);
// you can manually set camera viewport 
//camera=new OrthographicCamera(100*34,100*34);
```

You can also try this

```
camera=new OrthographicCamera(34,34);
float unitScale = 1 / 100f;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, unitScale);
```

Get more how unitScale works :
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps#rendering-tiled-maps

**EDIT**

I checked .tmx file, it has 3 layer. There is a `TiledMapImageLayer` at 0 index that's why it give you cast error. At index 1 and 2 there is `TiledMapTileLayer` so get layer from index 1.

I tried to load your .tmx in my code and it render on display.

```
public class TestGame extends Game {

    TiledMap map;
    OrthographicCamera camera;
    TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        TmxMapLoader tmxMapLoader=new TmxMapLoader();

        map=tmxMapLoader.load("ste_barbe_map.tmx");

        TiledMapTileLayer layer=(TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(1);

        tiledMapRenderer= new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.update();
        float widthHeightRatio=1.66f; 
        camera.setToOrtho(false,(layer.getWidth()*layer.getTileWidth())/widthHeightRatio,layer.getHeight()*layer.getTileHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();
    }
}
```

Map having same number of tile in horizontal and in vertical. Your game will be either in landscape or portrait so keep a ratio for this like(for landscape 25 tile in horizontal and 15 tile in vertical).

`widthHeightRatio` become 1 if you maintain ratio.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't working either. First solution gives me a cast error from TiledMapImageLayer to TiledMapTileLayer) and even with manually setting the camera to (100*34,100*34) doesn't work. Second option has the exact same results. Just a plain red background. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: i think you're using  TiledMapTileLayer layer=(TiledMapImageLayer) map.getLayers().get(0); instead of TiledMapTileLayer layer=(TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(0);

Comment: I am not but that shouldn't even matter if i am contructing the camera object like this: camera=new OrthographicCamera(100*34,100*34); Even then i only get a red screen

Comment: Basically this https://gyazo.com/5bcaadd528b548ccbd59fe681d805511 Nothing much changed

Comment: can i get your .tmx file ?

Comment: Sure let me see if i can send it somehow

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all your help!